# uploading empty file in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to POST json files in Powershell with this loop:

```
$negativeTests = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\ME\folder\folder\folder\"
#Write-Host $negativeTests;
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $negativeTests.Count; $i++) {
    $tempFile = Get-Content $negativeTests[$i].PSPath
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://testWebsite.com/ext/ext/ext -Method POST -Body $tempFile
}
```

However the output I'm getting from the server, specifically: `Content-Length: 52` indicates that Powershell is trying to literally upload the file *name*, not the contents (the file is 250+ bytes). How do I fix this so that Powershell knows to upload the actual contents (this is a JSON file)?

Comment: Fixed it. I needed to add the `-ContentType application/json` tag to my POST line: `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://testWebsite.com/ext/ext/ext -ContentType application/json -Method POST -Body $tempFile`

Comment: I posted your comment as an answer. Can you accept it? (I don't get any rep points BTW as it is marked community wiki)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP solved their own problem as follows:

Fixed it. I needed to add the -ContentType application/json tag to my POST line:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://testWebsite.com/ext/ext/ext -ContentType application/json -Method POST -Body $tempFile
```